# How to update a composite list as contents of member lists are changed?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, data-structures

Let's say I have:

```
friendlies = []
enemies = []
everyone = [friendlies + enemies]
```

And I say:

```
friendlies.append("something")
```

so that friendlies now contains:

```
["something"]
```

What is the pythonic way to make it so that `everyone` updates as well? So that if I update `friendlies` in the way stated above, `everyone` would contain:

```
["something"]
```

?

Comment: `[friendlies + enemies]` this gonna return `[[..elements.....]]`. Do you want that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a reference to `friendlies` and `enemies` in the composite list:

```
everyone = [friendlies, enemies]
#                     ^
```

Index 0 and 1 of the compisite list will reference `friendlies` and `enemies` respectively.

`friendlies + enemies` creates a new list which is not what you want.

---

A more readable approach will be making `everyone` a dictionary:

```
everyone = {'friendlies': friendlies, 'enemies': enemies}
```

And can be used as:

```
>>> friendlies = []
>>> enemies = []
>>> everyone = {'friendlies': friendlies, 'enemies': enemies}
>>> friendlies.append("something")
>>> everyone['friendlies']
['something']
```

Comment: Is there another way to append to both list `friendlies, enemies` using `everyone` without iterating everyone and appending to the list one at a time?

Comment: @MooingRawr Can you describe that in more detail

Comment: Want to do `for each in everyone: each.append("something")` is there another way to do this ?

Comment: @MooingRawr The other ways will also have an underlying iteration even if it's not obvious

Answer (score 1):

If you sum now you lose reference. Create a list of lists to maintain references

Hacky way of doing that:

```
friendlies = []
enemies = []

everyone = [friendlies,enemies]  # not sum, sublists
enemies.append("something")
print(sum(everyone,[]))   # sum sublists to a new list
```

Comment: Isn't that just like what Moses posted?

Comment: I think I'm in love with `sum` now, thanks you to.... Just need to find a job that let's me be with my new found lover.

Comment: Right: although just a python job would do! Next trick : `reduce`. Errr, no.